# Getting soapfault error

Tags: android, web-services, webservice-client

I am connecting my Android code with a `Webservice` to retrive data. and I am always getting:

```
 SoapFault - faultcode: 'a:InternalServiceFault' faultstring: 'Error in deserializing body of request message for operation
 'insertAuditData'. OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message
 body. Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'insertAuditData'
 and namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'. Found node type 'Element' with
 name 'insertAuditData' and namespace 'http://tempuri.org'' faultactor:
 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@44f6a4e8
```

my code is

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION3 = "http://tempuri.org/IService/GetSpecificAuditData";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION2 = "http://tempuri.org/IService/insertAuditData" ;
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IService/GetAllAuditData";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetAllAuditData";
private static final String METHOD_NAME2 = "insertAuditData";
private static final String METHOD_NAME3 = "GetSpecificAuditData";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org//";
private static final String URL = "http://70.33.215.18/PortalService.svc?wsdl";
private boolean isResultVector = false;

public Audit CallGetALL()
  {
    final String sGetSingle = METHOD_NAME;
    // Create the outgoing message
    final SoapObject requestObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, sGetSingle);
    // Create soap envelop .use version 1.1 of soap
    final SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    // add the outgoing object as the request
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(requestObject);
    envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE,Audit.Audit_CLASS.getSimpleName(),Audit.Audit_CLASS);
    // call and Parse Result.
    final Object response = this.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    Audit result = null;
    if (response != null)
        {
            result = new Audit((SoapObject) response);
        }

        return result;
    }
 protected Object call(String soapAction,SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope)
        {
            Object result = null;
            final HttpTransportSE transportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            transportSE.debug = false;
            // call and Parse Result.
            try
            {
                transportSE.call(soapAction, envelope);
                if (!isResultVector)
                {
                    result = envelope.getResponse();
                } else
                {
                    result = envelope.bodyIn;
                }
            } catch (final IOException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (final XmlPullParserException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (final Exception e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I got same issue but I can not solve it :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing that stands out is that you're not setting any properties on requestObject.

The serialized SOAP XML for GetSpecificAuditData probably looks something like this...
`<k:GetSpecificAuditData xmlns:k="http://tempuri.org//"></k:GetSpecificAuditData>`

The web service probably expects GetSpecificAuditData to have some data associated with it. Maybe a record ID? This is all just a guess on my part since I've no idea what the web service specification looks like.

Look at the addProperty method of SoapObject.

Also, double check your namespace. The trailing slash on the end might cause problems with the service as well.

If you're interested, I've written a tutorial on ksoap2-android which can be found at...

http://www.shanekirk.com/2011/11/speaking-soap-with-android/